# Polymer: Multiple templates for the same component, based on attribute?

Tags: templates, syntax, polymer, logic

I'm going slightly grey over here trying to figure out how one can go about having more than one template in a single Polymer component and resolving to a particular template based on an attribute.

Here's the scenario:

**Component**

```
<dom-module id="py-test">
    <template>
        Foo
    </template>
    <template>
        Bar
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "py-test"
        })
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

**Markup**

```
<py-test bar></py-test>
```

**Expected outcome**
If `<py-test></py-test>` has an attribute of bar, the component should use the second template. Otherwise, it should use the first template.

Anyone have a clue about how to beat Polymer into submission?

**// Edit**

Maria pointed out dom-if as a possible solution. Which does kind of work. I used the example above to add dom-if checks:

```
<dom-module id="py-test">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[foo]]">
            Foo
        </template>
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[bar]]">
            Bar
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "py-test",
            properties: {
                foo: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    value: true
                },
                bar: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    value: false
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

But I don't see how I can tie this with attributes set on the `<py-test>` element itself.

Comment: Would using a `dom-if` be an option?

Comment: @Maria It kind of does work with dom-if, in the sense that I can switch between templates by checking the truthiness of a particular function. But that doesn't help me much because I don't see how I can tie these boolean results to particular attributes set on the markup element. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe this is what you're looking for [iron-lazy-pages](https://github.com/TimvdLippe/iron-lazy-pages). Use the Polymer.Templatizer behavior to stamp your template based on the attribute

Comment: Just omit the values in the `properties` and then it should work. See this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PgiVKZDbzMIkCD4sYc1T?p=preview)

Comment: I'm going to post this as answer...

Comment: @Maria That's it! You're awesome! Please post this as the answer. Well done!

Comment: @MuhammadSayuti While that does work, it's very much overkill for what I'm trying to do. Not wrong by any stretch, just far too complex for my particular situation. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @RaduChelariu :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there in your edit. Just remove the initial values in the `properties` object.

```
<dom-module id="py-test">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[foo]]">
            Foo
        </template>
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[bar]]">
            Bar
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "py-test",
            properties: {
                foo: {
                    type: Boolean,
                },
                bar: {
                    type: Boolean,
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

You can then use it like this:

```
<py-test foo></py-test>
<py-test bar></py-test>
```

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PgiVKZDbzMIkCD4sYc1T?p=preview).

It can be slightly confusing how Polymer handles Boolean attributes. If they are present the associated property is `true`, else it's `false`. If you set initial values you are interfering with that.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Indeed, Polymer's got its quirks, but most frameworks do anyway. Thank you!